# How to keep reading input as long as the user wants to?

Tags: c++, alphabetical-sort

I am trying to sort an array of a list in string form into alphabetical order. I already have it being sorted alphabetically though, but it works until 6 items are entered. How can I code this so that it allows the user to input as many times as they want until they type "exit" where the program would output the alphabetized list? Thank you in advance!

```
int main(void)
{
const int MAX_LENGTH = 256;
string items [MAX_LENGTH];
int quantities [ MAX_LENGTH];
string itemChoice;
string quantityChoice;
int numberOfItems= 0;

cout <<  " (press enter to begin listing your 
list.): ";
getline(cin, itemChoice);  

cout << itemChoice << endl;
for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
{
    string itemChoice;
    cout << i << ". ";
    cin >> itemChoice;
    sortedItems.insert(itemChoice);
}
for_each(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), &print);    
return 0;      
}
```

Comment: Are you in a position to use `std::sort`?

Comment: @user4581301 If that is the only way then yes, but ideally no

Comment: Can you put the items into the list in sorted order as the user provides them?

Comment: Declare `sortedItems` like this : `set<string> sortedItems;`

Comment: @user4581301 no I can't

Comment: @SidS I actually do have that declared at the top, I just forget to add it

Comment: Well, in that case `sortedItems` is always sorted.  Maybe you should reconsider the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the loop infinite, and exit it when the user enters `"exit"`. So, remove the loop condition and add a test for `"exit"`:

```
for (int i = 1; ; i++)
{
    string itemChoice;
    cout << i << ". ";
    cin >> itemChoice;
    if (itemChoice == "exit")
    {
        break;
    }
    sortedItems.insert(itemChoice);
}
```